# Best API to do background task in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Which is fastest Kotlin Coroutines or Work Manager API to fetch images and videos from an Android phone. Or any other Methods ?

Comment: You can not compare it .. Because under the hood they all are mostly the same in terms of performance...  They vary in resource utilization.. Except each API you have mentioned have a different purpose in android..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutines are designed to provide a lightweight asynchronous programming framework. You can use Coroutines to start async job which is bounded to the local lifecycle scope of some part of your app. For example, if you want to call a REST API when the user clicks the "login" button. In this case, you don't really care if this result was complete (for example the user can go back and the task will cancel). If you need to be sure the task will complete then the WorkManager would be a better choice (e.g. it would be suitable for a long-running upload task which would be better to perform in the background).

If you'd like to see more about the practical use of coroutines for async jobs on Android I can recommend my article:
https://www.netguru.com/codestories/android-coroutines-%EF%B8%8Fin-2020